# Extremely new to R: Support.CEs package - help with design matrix please!

Tags: experiment-design, matrix, choice-modeling

I've only started using R one day ago, still so much to get my head around. I need to create a choice experiment, and I have been following the [example of H.Aizaki](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v50/c02/paper)

I think I have created a successful choice experiment design using the input below.

```
des1 <- rotation.design(attribute.names = list( Pepper = c("Black", "Mountain Hot", "Mountain Mild"), Packaging = c("Refill", "Grinder", "Shaker"), Label = c("Australia", "Tasmania", "Import"), Price = c("0.50", "1.25", "3.00")),nalternatives = 2, nblocks = 1, row.renames = FALSE,randomize = TRUE, seed = 987)
des1
```

and have converted it into a questionnaire format too. I need to make a design matrix now. I have used:

```
desmat1 <- make.design.matrix(choice.experiment.design = des1, optout = TRUE, categorical.attributes = c("Pepper", "Packaging", "Label"), continuous.attributes = c("Price"), unlabeled = TRUE)
desmat1[1:100, ]
```

But it only lists the first 27 lines (9 questions per survey, 3 options per question, so only 1 survey has been listed) before it says 'NA' e.g.

```
BLOCK QES ALT ASC Mountain.Hot Mountain.Mild Grinder Shaker Tasmania

..............

25        1   9   1   1            0             1       0      0        1

26        1   9   2   1            0             1       0      1        0

27        1   9   3   0            0             0       0      0        0

NA       NA  NA  NA  NA           NA            NA      NA     NA       NA

NA.1     NA  NA  NA  NA           NA            NA      NA     NA       NA

NA.2     NA  NA  NA  NA           NA            NA      NA     NA       NA
```

Ideally I need 100 surveys (so 2700 lines I think???).

I would love some help! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi @Glen_b, yes I have. I've been following the unlabeled example (4.1) beginning on page 14 of the paper. It's very useful, except for where I'm having trouble! At the bottom of page 16, the output for the design matrix has been limited to 3 lines of data, so 1 out of 9 questions for 1 survey. I need all 9 of 9 questions for 100 surveys. (obviously it would take up too much room to show all 100, as each survey would need 27 lines) but that's the part I'm having trouble with! I don't have data yet to create a data set, but I wanted to test the design matrix before I started the experiment.

Comment: Ah, I see now you even mentioned it, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with that package, but I note that your commands nowhere specify how many questionnaires you need. From context, it appears reasonable that it takes 27 of them to make one full replication. So if you need about 100, use 4 copies of each of the 27 rows -- 108 total -- and randomly order them:

```
des <- rbind(desmat1, desmat1, desmat1, desmat1)
des <- des[sample(1:108), ]
```

Perhaps the designer of that package provides a capability for something like this, perhaps as an optional argument in make.design.matrix. Try

```
? make.design.matrix
```

Comment: Sorry @RussLenth it's probably my fault I didn't explain it clearly. One replication would be 9 questions (1 questionnaire), which is 27 lines in the design matrix as each question requires 3 lines (3 alternatives). So I need 100 questionnaires with the same 9 questionnaires in each, which would be 2700 lines. (I tried those commands in any case but still had 'NA' appear after 27 lines/1 survey). I had a look through the help command but nothing mentioned that was relevant as far as I could tell. Thanks though.